# MySQL 5.1 - Display the error-message returned inside a stored precedure

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, mysql-5.1

I'm trying to find an alternative to display the error-message 
returned from MySQL-**5.1/5.5** inside a stored procedure.

The example below is what I'm looking for, however it's seems to be only allowed in **version 5.6+** :

```
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
BEGIN
      GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1
      code = RETURNED_SQLSTATE, 
      error_string = MESSAGE_TEXT;
END;
```

Is there any alternative to skip this obstacle and get the original error message returned by MySQL during the execution of the stored procedure?

Thanks.

Comment: Didn't you ask this question somewhere else?  And get an answer there?

Comment: That was for MySQL version 5.6+, whatt I'm asking is if there is another solution to perform the same thing with MySQL 5.1 ( it's a subject of research).

Comment: A bit of history...  The initial implementation (in 5.1?) of Stored Routines was pretty lame and left out a lot of rather important features.  I suspect (without hard knowledge) that there is no good solution in 5.1.